# build custom pagination logic without jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm stuck at how to proceed with my custom pagination. In the example I don't have the content part but I know how to do that, just hide and show base on the index clicked.

I'm stuck at how to split and handle the element into better UX, like this
[image]

http://jsbin.com/qulipamecu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
var html = '';
for(var i in item){
    html += '<li>' + item[i] + '</li>';
  }
```

Comment: Please add more of the code you added to the jsbin, it's a perfectly valid question you have, and it makes sense to add it here

Answer (score 3):

To do split the UI for the pagination is not really that hard, depending on how complex you wish to make it

As an example, I re-implemented the code in your jsbin without the help of jQuery, and added a function called `isPageInRange`, this function will check if your page is currently in range, and return true or false for it.

So the main logic changes are the following:

```
for(var i in item){
  if ( isPageInRange( curPage, i, pageLen, 2, 2 ) ) {
    html += '<li data-page="' + i + '">' + item[i] + '</li>';
    // as we added a page, we reset the separatorAdded
    separatorAdded = false;
  } else {
    if (!separatorAdded) {
      // only add a separator when it wasn't added before
      html += '<li class="separator" />';
      separatorAdded = true;
    }
  }
}
```

In case the page is not in range, you can just add a separator (when not added yet -> you don't want multiple separators next to each other)

The sample assumes that:

- You want to have the first 2 pages always visible
- You want the last 2 pages always visible
- You want to configure how many pages before and after your current page should be active

For the rest, I made some small changes, eg:

- (active) selection is based on data-page attribute
- full div is clickable (and click handler is added only the first time)
- full div is re-rendered when the pages change

```js
var pageLen = 20;
var curPage = 2;
var item = [];
for(var i = 1; i<=pageLen;i++){
   item.push(i);
}

function isPageInRange( curPage, index, maxPages, pageBefore, pageAfter ) {
  if (index <= 1) {
    // first 2 pages
    return true;
  }
  if (index >= maxPages - 2) {
    // last 2 pages
    return true;
  }
  if (index >= curPage - pageBefore && index <= curPage + pageAfter) {
    return true;
  }
}

function render( curPage, item, first ) {
  var html = '', separatorAdded = false;
  for(var i in item){
    if ( isPageInRange( curPage, i, pageLen, 2, 2 ) ) {
      html += '<li data-page="' + i + '">' + item[i] + '</li>';
      // as we added a page, we reset the separatorAdded
      separatorAdded = false;
    } else {
      if (!separatorAdded) {
        // only add a separator when it wasn't added before
        html += '<li class="separator" />';
        separatorAdded = true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  var holder = document.querySelector('#holder');  
  holder.innerHTML = html;
  document.querySelector('#holder>li[data-page="' + curPage + '"]').classList.add('active');
  if ( first ) {
    holder.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (!e.target.getAttribute('data-page')) {
        // no relevant item clicked (you could however offer expand here )
        return;
      }
      curPage = parseInt( e.target.getAttribute('data-page') );
      render( curPage, item );
    });
  }
}

render( 2, item, true );
```

```css
#holder > li {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#holder > li[data-page] {
  border: solid #a0a0a0 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#holder > li.separator:before {
  content: '...';
}
#holder > li.active {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: #fff;
}
#holder > li[data-page]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder"></div>
```